# How to get Knockout dialog to update

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I got this dialog popup  that I want to update with a selected Text.

```
<div data-bind="with: SelectedText">
    <div id="dialog" data-bind="dialog: {'autoOpen': false, 'title': textbatchTitle }, dialogVisible: $root.isMetadataDialogOpen">
        <div class="metadata">
            <label for="textbatchTitle">Title:</label> <span class="rotten">Why isen´t this updated with SelectText after pushing "Add New Text"?"</span>
            <input type="text" name="textbatchTitle" data-bind="value: textbatchTitle, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It seems the dialog does´t respond to the "with"-binding?

This is my custom binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.dialog = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()) || {};

        //do in a setTimeout, so the applyBindings doesn't bind twice from element being copied and moved to bottom
        setTimeout(function () {
            options.close = function () {
                allBindingsAccessor().dialogVisible(false);
            };

            $(element).dialog(ko.toJS(options));
        }, 0);

        //handle disposal (not strictly necessary in this scenario)
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
            $(element).dialog("destroy");
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var shouldBeOpen = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor().dialogVisible),
            $el = $(element),
            dialog = $el.data("uiDialog") || $el.data("dialog"),
            options = valueAccessor();

        //don't call dialog methods before initilization
        if (dialog) {
            $el.dialog(shouldBeOpen ? "open" : "close");

            for (var key in options) {
                if (ko.isObservable(options[key])) {
                    $el.dialog("option", key, options[key]());
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

What is wrong with this? 
http://jsfiddle.net/qFjRW/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't include jquery ui as an external source:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dialog'
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/FXTHn

**EDIT:**

Since you're using the `with: SelectedText` outside of the dialog, it won't call `update` when `SelectedText` changes. Try placing it inside:

```
<div id="dialog" data-bind="dialog: {'autoOpen': false, 'title': SelectedText().textbatchTitle }, dialogVisible: $root.isMetadataDialogOpen">
    <div data-bind="with: SelectedText">
        <div class="metadata">
            <label for="textbatchTitle">Title:</label> <span class="rotten">Why isen´t this updated with SelectText after pushing "Add New Text"?"</span>
            <input type="text" name="textbatchTitle" data-bind="value: textbatchTitle, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FXTHn/1/

Comment: Yes, that´s the reason the dialog does´t pop up, but still the dialog show some rather strange behavior; it does´t update and when adding new texts, additional popups shows.

Comment: Great! Thanx! Big help! Appreciate it. :)